# How Can I Prevent Spring Boot jUnit IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I created a simple model and repository layers using spring boot data jpa. To test these layers, I want to write unit test code over junit and test the code. But I am getting error as below. How can I get around this error and test my code?

**Error log message:**

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.jav

a:177)
```

**Model Layer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal price;

    //getter setter
}
```

**RepositoryLayer**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name IS NOT NULL order by p.id ASC")
    public List<Product> findAllProducts();

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name = ?1 order by p.id ASC")
    public List<Product> findProductsByName(String name);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price = ?1 order by p.id ASC")
    public List<Product> findProductsByPrice(BigDecimal price);
}
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
@DataJpaTest
public class JpaTest {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    public void getProductByIdTest() {
        Product c = productRepository.findById(1L).get();

        Assertions.assertThat(c.getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring needs the @SpringBootTest annotation to look for the main class configuration and use that class to start the application context.

Try the following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
public class JpaTest {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    public void getProductByIdTest() {
        Product c = productRepository.findById(1L).get();

        Assertions.assertThat(c.getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get "Test ignored." with your code.